# AWS CLI Instance ID in variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi can someone help with this

I am using the Amazon AWS CLI command in a bash script and have the following line and the output it gives.

```
 aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $Ins --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value]' --output text

    ' does not existd (InvalidInstanceID.NotFound) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: 

The instance ID 'i-0c7bf4181bdfxxxxx Will be backed up
```

If I echo the value of $ins and hard code it in the command like

```
$ echo $Ins
i-0c7bf4181bdfxxxxx

$ aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-0c7bf4181bdfxxxxx --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value]' --output text
lon-prod-xxxx-xxxx
```

I don't understand why it works in the command when copied and pasted but not when used as a variable?

Additional Code, sure there are neater ways to do this but just need something quick. Just grabbing all the instance ids from a single VPC and then attempting to take an image of each in turn.

```
Instances=$(aws ec2  describe-instances --filter "Name=vpc-id,Values=$VPCID" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId]' --output text)

for Ins in $Instances; do
echo $Ins
name=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $Ins --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value]' --output text)
echo $name Will be backed up
echo $Ins
aws ec2 create-image --instance-id $Ins --name "$name" --description "Auto backed up on $(date)" --no-reboot --$dryrun
echo "***"
done
enter code here
```

error is below, the first id is where i am echoing $Ins so it seems to know the ID, but i think it has a /r /n after it

```
     i-0c7bf4181bdfxxxxx

    ' does not existd (InvalidInstanceID.NotFound) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: 
The instance ID 'i-0c7bf4181bdfxxxxx Will be backed up
```

Comment: Your command is good. It looks like there is something wrong with the instance-id in the variable. The error message is misleading. Can you describe the complete error message?

Comment: That is it, i will add more above as to the code snipt i am trying to run

Comment: I tried the following script and it works like a charm: `Ins=i-1234567 ; aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $Ins --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value]' --output text`. It prints the instance name.

Comment: Same here, if i manauly set up the variable it works, but if i try to get a list and loop though it, it seems to have problems

Answer (score 1):

OK I fixed it, the variable did have a new line after it "/r"

Added this line

Ins=${Ins/$'\r'/} to strip it out and works OK now.